# Guassian quadrature

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

Consider the polynomial $L \in P_5$ defined by 
$$L(x)=\frac{d}{dx^3}(1-x^2)^4$$
My question is to use a technique similar to the one used in the analysis of the Gaussian
quadrature to show that Q has degree of precision 7

---

What The degree of precision of the quadrature formula is $\leq 2n-1$. We let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $\leq 2n-1$. We divide $P$ by $L$
 be a polynomial. 
   $P(x) = Q(x) L(x) + R(x)$
where Q and R are degree n−1 . We want to show that P has degree 7 but we know that L is degree 5. Does this mean that $Q$ and $R$ must be degree 4?

Comment: Use a technique similar to the one used in the analysis of the Gaussian quadrature to show that $Q$ has degree of precision 7. where $Q(f) = \sum_{i=0}^{4}w_if(ξ_i)$ @Amzoti

Comment: So we want to show that P has degree 7 but we know that L is degree 5. @Amzoti

Comment: But my question is what are the degree of $Q$ and $R$. Is it 4?